# Conditional tests in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Is there a way to group tests conditionally with rspec? By which I mean, is there a way to say "if this variable is some value, run this set of tests. If this variable is some other variable, run this other set of tests"?

Basic Example of where it would be needed (doesn't actually work, obviously, but should show you what I want). Assume the user to be tested is defined elsewhere and the current user being tested is @user. Although you may have better alternatives to that, that's fine.

```
before do 
  login_as_user(@user) #This logs them in and brings them to the homepage to be tested
  page.visit("/homepage")
end
describe "Check the user homepage"
  subject {page}
  it {should have_content("Welcome, #{@user.name}!")}
  if(@user.role=="admin")
    it {should have_link("List Users"}
  end
end
```

Keep in mind I have no control over the user being tested - I cannot create users on the fly, for example, and no given user is guaranteed to exist, and I don't know offhand what combination of roles a given user will have. So I do need some way to say "run this test only if these conditions are met", rather than a way to create situations where every test can be run.

Comment: I'm curious as to what the actual use case for this is.

Comment: I have to write some assertion tests for several users with pretty complicated permission setups. The most common case will be I will want to check the users attributes to see if they have permission to view a given page - if they do, I want to run the standard tests, if they don't I want to insure they get the right permission denied page for the page they are visiting. There are a variety of users with a variety of permissions (and permission inheritance) that will need to be checked.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't have separate `describe`/`context` blocks for the different test circumstances, and then mock/stub the user's permissions in a `before` in each context?

Comment: Since I'm doing acceptance testing on an actual page (through capybara), mocks won't work since it won't be valid session data. Unless you mean something other than what I think you mean with that. You know what, I'll throw one a basic use case up there, and if you think there's a way to rewrite it with describes and stubs, feel free - If it will work, I'm open to it.

Comment: I've found that conditional logic DOES actually work when looped around tests - You can do things like on this page for example: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/470 However, it's a SCOPE problem - @user doesn't exist as far as the logic is concerned. Hmmm...

Comment: http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/specs-and-testing/dry-your-tests-with-dynamic-specs-in-rspec seems to have some good info on the sort of thing I want to be able to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, apparently the issue was as simple as this: @user is an instance variable, which only exists when the tests are being executed. Dynamic generation of tests does not work with instance variables for that reason.

However, by declaring it as a local variable somewhere outside any test-style blocks (before, after, it or specify), you can have access to it for the conditional logic.

The solution was as simple as taking the @ sign off the front of the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`let`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) (or possibly `let!`) to define who the user being logged-in should be. (Obviously replace `@regular_user` & `@admin_user` with the appropriate factory/fixture/etc.)

```
before do
  login_as_user(user)
  page.visit "/homepage"
end
let(:user) { @regular_user }

describe "Check the user homepage" do
  subject { page }
  it { should have_content "Welcome, #{@user.name}!" }

  context "when an administrator" do
    let(:user) { @admin_user }
    it { should have_link "List Users" }
  end
end
```

Comment: Since I have no access to the system I'm testing, factories/fixtures for this sort of thing are right out. And there is, unfortunately, no guarantee a given user will exist (and since they can't be made, I still need a way to not run the admin_user tests if there is no admin_user). This approach actually does have some interesting uses I'll consider, but I'm not entirely sure it will resolve my problem. I'll make a note in the original problem as to the inability to create users as needed.

Answer (score 0):

in the same kind of idea you can use static variables

In order to easily switch between environment, I even use the system global variables

in my spec_helper.rb, I've set the default settings

```
default_env = {
  'SITE_ROOT' => "http://localhost:3000",
  'ACCOUNT_ID' => 'user',
  'ACCOUNT_PASSWORD' => 'password',
  'SUBMIT_REAL_MONEY' => 'false'
}

# setting default env variables if no ENV ones exists
default_env.each do |const_name, value|
  val = ENV[const_name].nil? ? value : ENV[const_name]
  eval_str = "#{const_name}='#{val}'"
  puts eval_str
  eval eval_str
end
```

Then I can specify my settings in the command line calling my specs:

```
SITE_ROOT='https://my.production.site/' SUBMIT_REAL_MONEY=true rspec
```

And here is a spec behind a simple condition:

```
if SUBMIT_REAL_MONEY == 'true'
  it { should respond_with 200 }
end
```